# how to explode a date in laravel 5 in controller

Tags: php, laravel, date

hi i want to convert my jalali date that i get from input to Georgian so i can save it as Georgian in database . so i get the date in this format

```
1397/5/29
```

for example now in my controller i want to convert it to gerogian i use a library that it converts the date like this .

```
   Verta::getGregorian(1394,10,4); // [2015,12,25]
```

so now i want to seperate the string that i had in my controller and place it inside that function i searched i found that i can do it with explode but i have no idea how it works in laravel .
here is how i get my input and i want to explode

```
$calldate = $request->calldate;
```

Comment: `explode` like any other PHP function can simply be used in Laravel.

Comment: Remember, Laravel is not a new language, its just a framework built over standard PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the hood, Laravel is just a PHP application ... so you can use PHPs native explode function directly in your controller like this ...

```
$date = explode('/', '1397/5/29');
```

This tells php to split the string every time it encounters a slash and add it to the $date array:

```
[0=>"1397", 1=>"5", 2=>"29"]
```

... that you can feed into you function like this:

```
Verta::getGregorian($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
```